# Compile Failed because of Strong Name

Tags: .net, compilation, strongname

There're two dlls I want to reference in my project. They are A.dll and B.dll. B.dll referenced A.dll. They don't have strong name. My project C need to sign strong name. So I need to sign strong name to both A.dll and B.dll. After that, I got a problem - I can't compile success, code of B.dll could not convert to type include in A.dll.
I know why this happen. I sign strong name to both A.dll and B.dll, but B.dll still reference the A.dll without strong name.
So my question is, how to sign strong name to B.dll and B.dll referenced A.dll. not only reference B.dll or A.dll.
Here is the projects and error messages:
[image]

Comment: A: do you really *need* to sign C? If so: why? ... And B: do you have access to A and B? i.e. could you rebuild them?

Comment: Yes, i really need to sign C. It's requirement. I don't have access to A and B. If so, I can do as you said, rebuild them, then my problem is resolved.

Comment: Yes, but the signature is part of the identity. If you change the identity. You most-likely break the relationship between A and B....

Comment: So, there's no solution for this issue?

Comment: If the assembly is marked as Delayed Signed then you can use sn.exe to sign it....else if its not marked Delayed Signed and you dont have the source to A and B, then you can do this: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx  ...   http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing

Comment: Thanks guys, I find the solution: http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! here is the solution: http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing